# Typescript: How to infer types from a generic that may or may not be an element of an array

Tags: typescript, generics

In this contrived example I have a generic function that prints the position of a value within an array and resolves a label for it:

```
function printOne<T>(value: T, config: { opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string }) {
  console.log(config.opts.indexOf(value), config.label(value));
}
```

Example calls:

```
printOne(1, {
  opts: [3, 5, 6, 1, 4],
  label: (x) => `Number(${x})`,
});
// 3 "Number(1)"

printOne("b", {
  opts: ["a", "b", "c"],
  label: (x) => `Char(${x})`,
});
// 1 "Char(b)"
```

I want to implement another function that calls `printOne`, and does so multiple times if the first argument happens to be an array of values instead of a singular value. Such that:

```
printPossiblyMany(1, {
  opts: [3, 5, 6, 1, 4],
  label: (x) => `Number(${x})`,
});
// 3 "Number(1)"

printPossiblyMany([1, 3], {
  opts: [3, 5, 6, 1, 4],
  label: (x) => `Number(${x})`,
});
// 3 "Number(1)"
// 0 "Number(3)"

printPossiblyMany("b", {
  opts: ["a", "b", "c"],
  label: (x) => `Char(${x})`,
});
// 1 "Char(b)"

printPossiblyMany(["b", "c"], {
  opts: ["a", "b", "c"],
  label: (x) => `Char(${x})`,
});
// 1 "Char(b)"
// 2 "Char(c)"
```

I've attempted to implement such a function by conditionally typing the config:

```
export function printPossiblyMany<T>(
  value: T,
  config: T extends Array<infer E>
    ? { opts: E[]; label: (x: E) => string }
    : { opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string }
) {
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    for (const elem of value) {
      printOne(elem, config);
    }
  } else {
    printOne(value, config);
  }
}
```

#### Issue 1

Both calls of `printOne` have type mismatches on the `config` argument. The first is anotated with:

```
Argument of type 'T extends (infer E)[] ? { opts: E[]; label: (x: E) => string; } : { opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }'.
  Type '{ opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; } | { opts: unknown[]; label: (x: unknown) => string; }' is not assignable to type '{ opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }'.
    Type '{ opts: unknown[]; label: (x: unknown) => string; }' is not assignable to type '{ opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }'.
      Types of property 'opts' are incompatible.
        Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'T'.
            'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'unknown'.
```

And the second with:

```
Argument of type 'T extends (infer E)[] ? { opts: E[]; label: (x: E) => string; } : { opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ opts: T[]; label: (x: T) => string; }'.
```

Presumably the scope of `Array.isArray` is doing something but not enough to fully resolve the types. Is there a resolution to this error that doesn't involve disabling type safety?

#### Issue 2

Furthermore, typescript only accepts calls to `printPossiblyMany` for an array of values if the type parameter is made explicit. E.g.:

```
printPossiblyMany(["b", "c"], {
  opts: ["a", "b", "c"],
  label: (x) => `Char(${x})`,
});
```

errors on the first argument with:

```
Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

but the following is accepted:

```
printPossiblyMany<string[]>(["b", "c"], {
  opts: ["a", "b", "c"],
  label: (x) => `Char(${x})`,
});
```

Can the function signature be typed in such a way that array types are implicitly detected?

Comment: Is it something [like this](https://replit.com/@ffflabs/SwelteringFlawlessClasslibrary#index.ts) that you're looking for?

Comment: Yes! So my mistake was to make the config's type adaptive instead of the value's type. Much simpler, thank you!

Comment: Is it otherwise impossible to define the config's type in terms of the value's? I actually extracted this problem from a larger one that I'm trying to solve, which involves mapping over inferred key-value types. I suppose I'm possibly asking the wrong question, and it probably makes more sense for me to start a new post with the full context.

Comment: I'm not proficient enough, but I can tell you you're not providing enough info to the compiler. For starters, your functions  returnType is always null. Elaborating in the output type, in which T comes out cleanly, might be suited for my approach, but this is not the solution. I just wanted to confirm your expected results before doing some investigation

Comment: Are return types going to make a difference to my example? I know your example was written using non-imperative functional-style, but isn't that inconsequential to the problem at hand?

Comment: Having actual outputs I could type  helped a lot when it came to understanding the compiler complaints.  They were in short two additional probes,

Comment: Right gotcha, that makes sense.